# Observable lists of objects with changing properties

Tags: c#, wpf, events, collections

I have a hierarchy of items like the following:

```
MainClass
{
    List<Configuration> MyList = new List<Configuration>;
}

Configuration
{
    CustomObject MyObject = new CustomObject;
    string Property = "";
}

CustomObject
{
    string InnerProperty = "";
}
```

If I want that `MainClass` gets notified from every change made to `InnerProperty` and `Property`, am I correct to assume that I have to transform the `List` into an `ObservableCollection` and that both `Configuration` and `CustomObject` should derive from `INotifyPropertyChanged`, right?

If I want only to get a notify when `InnerProperty` gets changed, and NOT `Property`, should only `CustomObject` derive from `INotifyPropertyChanged` or `Configuration` too (since I would lose the notification transmission to the parent)?

Comment: Please post the actual classes so that we have something concrete to work from.

Comment: It was only something conceptual but ok

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping for something that compiles and actually raises the required events. Please don't make us do too much work to answer your question.

Comment: As I said, I was only raising a conceptual question, I'm trying to understand how PropertyChanged events are recursively passing through objects and lists

Answer (score 2):

To get notification about InnerProperty and Property you don't need ObservableCollection in general. ObservableCollection is only for notifications about added\removed items. So you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on both Configuration and CustomObject. If you are only interested in changes of InnerProperty, INotifyPropertyChanged on Configuration is not necessary in case your MyObject property never changes and assigned in constructor. Otherwise, you need again to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on both. Same story with ObservableCollection by the way - if your list contains fixed list of items - you don't need that to receive notifications from properties. Otherwise you do.

Comment: I agree with Evk, INotifiyPropertyChanged will be required in both CustomObject and Configuration.

I have written an article that can help you @ http://emoreau.com/Entries/Articles/2015/07/Net-Observable-Collections.aspx

Answer (score 1):

> If I want only to get a notify when InnerProperty gets changed, and NOT Property, should only CustomObject derive from INotifyPropertyChanged or CustomObject too (since I would lose the notification transmission to the parent)?

(I assume that for the second `CustomObject` in that sentence you actually mean `Configuration`.)

If you only change `InnerProperty` and `MyProperty` doesn't change, then you only need to have `CustomObject` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. There is no sense of changes propagating up the chain.

If you have a binding path:

```
{Binding Path=A.B.C.D}
```

Then if any of those properties change and you want the binding to update, then the relevant level must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. If a property is immutable (doesn't change) then there's no need to support notification of changes. You can think that the binding is listening for changes on each object returned through the evaluation of the binding path.

Comment: And if I have to make some operations (let's say call a myMainClassMethod) in MainClass's codebehind when a property of CustomObject gets changed? Is it right to suppose that i could either make CustomObject implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and on MainClass write MyList[index].MyObject.PropertyChanged+=myMainClassMethod, or make both CustomObject and Configuration implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and write on MainClass MyList[index].PropertyChanged+=myMainClassMethod and on Configuration MyObject.PropertyChanged+=SomethingInvokingPropertyChanged?Note: probably wrong list item access

Comment: I don't see why you'd have to subscribe to `PropertyChanged` yourself. WPF bindings do this behind the scenes automatically.

Comment: I don't get it; what do you mean? Which subscription is unnecessary?

Comment: In your comment you use `PropertyChanged +=` several times and I don't think you should use it at all. Why don't you replace the psuedocode in your question with compiling code, then we can see the implementation you're having trouble with.

Comment: If I had some code I would have written it; but I was trying to understand the mechanism before undergoing some coding-changing-recoding-rechanging....

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer your conceptual question. But code is nice...

I'll first just point to [C#:: When to use events or a collection of objects derived from an event handling Interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/937318/5336967), which I think is quite helpful.

`ObservableCollection` takes care of raising events when items are added or removed. There is no need for INotifyPropertyChanged, that is automatically there. If you bind to an `ObservableCollection` in your `XAML`, then your `XAML` will register for those events, and you don't need to do anything yourself.  However, nothing else is listening to the events, unless you register. You can do that like this:

```
myObservablecollection.CollectionChanged += myHandler;
```

But I don't think that is what you want. If you want to now when something is added to, or removed from `MainClass.MyList`, then making it an `ObservableCollection` will do that for you. But you want to know when some particular item in your list is modified, and `ObservableCollection` does not help with that.

Let's suppose you want a `Configuration` to do something when its `CustomObject` changes. Perhaps it sets `Property` (not a good name?) to `MyObject.ToString()`. Then you make `CustomObject` implement INotifyPropertyChanged, like this:

```
Class CustomObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _innerProperty;
    public string InnerProperty 
      {get { return _innerProperty; }
      {set 
         {
              _innerProperty = value;
              OnPropertyChanged("InnerProperty");
         }
      }

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
      {
         if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
           PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
      }
}
```

Then in Configuration:

```
Class Configuration
{
    ...
    public Configuration(...)
    {
       ... // set up stuff
       MyObject.PropertyChanged += myObjectChanged_DoSomethingAboutIt;
    }

    private void myObjectChanged_DoSomethingAboutIt()
    {
         DoSomething();

         // for example:
         Property = MyObject.ToString();
    }
}
```

I hope this helps a bit.
More here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41817/Implementing-INotifyPropertyChanged